# Exclude certain subfolders when scanning the contents of a folder

Tags: batch-file, directory, subdirectory, findstr

I have a batch file that I'm using to scan the c:\ folders (and their respective subfolders) on a Windows 7 box using a for loop. I am having issues in excluding certain folders, such as Users, Windows, LocalAppData etc.

I need to scan through folders in C:\ to find a specific named folder (i.e. "myFolder") without scanning through the above mentioned folders in order to increase the time taken to detect the desired folder within the C: folder.

CODE:

```
@echo off

for /d /r "c:\" %%a in (*) do (
    findstr /v "Users" "Windows"
)
```

Comment: Please show your code and explain what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Hexaholic have just added my code above

Comment: If you know where the folder, _whose name does not appear anywhere in your code incidentally_, isn't at, perhaps you could give us some idea of where it may be, `\Program Files*` perhaps? Your question appears a little confused because `LocalAppData` is already in `Users`, so should be excluded by the `FindStr`, ***note the obvious typo in your code!***

Comment: The folder I am searching for can be in any folder within the C drive but not in Program Files or Users. Even if the typo is fixed, it still doesn't work. @Compo

Comment: Make your mind up! You said `Users`, `Windows` and `LocalAppData`, then your code said, `Users` and `Windows`, and now you're saying `Users` and `Program Files`. In a standard Windows setup structure, system directories excepted, (`$Recycle.Bin`, `Recovery` and `System Volume Information`), there are usually these directories: `PerfLogs`, `Program Files`, `Program Files (x86)`, `ProgramData`, `Users` and `Windows`. You've already ruled out four of those six; can you please better explain your task.

Comment: The folders I do not want to include in scanning are Program files, Program files (x86), Windows and Users. The most common ones that contain a lot of subfolders and files. Any of those can be just replaced and exchanged with other ones within the code as they are simple strings. The point I am focusing on, is how to exclude any desired folders during the execution of a for loop. @Compo

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %%D in ('dir /B /S /A:D "C:\myFolder" ^| findstr /I /V /C:"\\Users\\" /C:"\\Windows\\"') do echo/%%D`? (or, with the exeptions stored in a text file `exclude.txt`, replace the `findstr` part by `findstr /I /V /L /G:"exclude.txt"`)

Comment: To also prevent traversing System directories and Junctions you could probably extend that further: `@For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/S/AD-S-L "C:\myFolder"^|FindStr /IVC:"\\Users\\" /C:"\\Windows\\" /C:"\\Program Files\\" /C:"\\Program Files (x86)\\" 2^>Nul') Do @Echo=%%A`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`dir` command](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) to return the paths of all wanted directories `myFolder`, filter them by the [`findstr` command](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html), then capture the result by a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html), like this:

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%D in ('dir /B /S /A:D "C:\myFolder" ^| findstr /I /V /C:"\\Users\\" /C:"\\Windows\\"') do echo/%%D
```

Of course you can specify more exclusions.

---

If you want to have the exceptions located in a text file `C:\exclude.txt`:

> ```cmd
> Users
> Windows
> ```

Change the approach like this:

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%D in ('dir /B /S /A:D "C:\myFolder" ^| findstr /I /V /L /G:"C:\exclude.txt"') do echo/%%D
```